# Story of Fuzzy Nazi

Tags: lateral-thinking, visual

A team of scientists were doing some nature-survey works at a forest-area in Germany. Suddenly they noticed, there is a cottage, probably very old.
[image: The Cottage].
They decided to take a visit to it, when they will get some time.

But when they reached to the cottage, it did not seem anyone lives there. discolored, places-to-places covered with lichen. The wooden cottage was broken on places. There were cobwebs, also ditchy places where snakes may easily stay.

When they reached the front side of the cottage, a shock was waiting. Just beside an window, a big, approx 3 feet X 3 feet, very rusty iron signboard was showing something what looks like a Swastika.
[image: The signboard].

The team became quite frightened because they thought it could be a Nazi office or club, and there could be bombs remaining for many years.   They informed about it to the security personnels.

The next day security personnels said no bombs or any other weapons found (except an ordinary cooking knife),  They also found some household utensils, many books, mostly on literature (with many of them highly damaged due to rainfalls), but none of them was seemed related to Nazi political ideology. A bunch of paintbrushes found, a broken easel, some torn canvas with illegible images. In a trunk, along with some clothings and towels, miscellaneous study-objects like fountain-pens, pencils etc  along with some diaries and notebooks from which it seems the owner of the cottage was an old woman who lived alone in this cottage, wrote poems, did paintings, and strongly disliked anything about war.

No, could you tell, why that signboard was used?

Comment: Do you *really* need "try without hints" as a hint?

Comment: @Deusovi Okay I'm removing the hints.

Comment: If anyone think they can edit and suggest an improve, they plz feel free to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That one is pretty simple:

> If you look closely at the signboard you will see a number a 56 or 59 so I think it is a house number plaque, although it would be a relatively big one since normal ones are about 8" by 15".

Comment: "Fun" fact: Did you know that the House Number Plague killed all people in Europe who lived in houses whose numbers weren't divisible by three, thereby reducing the population to roughly 33%? `:)`

Comment: @MOehm I didn't knew.

Comment: @MOehm A strange correlation!

Comment: The big house number is just to display it from distance so that delivery person who brings paints etc can find the window  from distance.

Comment: @MOehm could not find "House Number Plague" in wikipedia and google.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Plague AKA The Black Death was one of the most devastating pandemics that killed from 75-200 million people in mid 14th century, I made a typo in my answer, an auto correction typo

Comment: @SherlockHolmes Not that. "House number" plague. When I typed "house number plague" on google, it gave house number plaque.

Answer (score 1):

Probably not but I think that -if I understand the puzzle correctly- :

> It was there as a protection for her, so when the germans pass by the cottage they would think she is a nazi, and leave her alone.

Comment: +1'd for a try, but that is not the actual answer.

Comment: I was thinking there was something written on the sign that rusted off in the shape of a swastika.

Comment: @Forklift Seems you are on correct way

Comment: It could be the number 59 or 55, because the vertical central strokes of the "swastika" aren't aligned. But 3' x 3' is a bit big for a house number plaque.

Comment: @MOehm Yes it is answer. Please write it as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Forklift yeah I thought the same A number like 56, But still trying to find a connection.

Comment: Okay, one puzzle could have >1 answers. Actually it  is a story form of a real  signboard I saw once.

Comment: I thought that it was like a house number but then said a 3m*3m is defiantly not, my bad :)

Comment: @S.Rafael Not meter, it is foot. From begining.

Comment: The reason of @MOehm is correct.

Comment: The connection with a larger, yellow signboard is not a big deal. Just so that postman/ delivery persons can see it from distance. The name of the village    (hypothetical) and detailed address with smaller font was at  door, which is no more. The window was used as letterbox.

Answer (score 0):

> Just in a calculator-like (7-segment-like) font there was written 55 (also  each digit could be 6, 8 or 9).
>
>
>
>  [image]
>
>
>  The window used as letterbox, where a delivery person dropped paints, brushes etc. The house number was drawn on big signboard so that delivery persons and postmen could see it from distance. The main address box with village name and other details was at door or such place which is no more.